# Is it possible to change Windows 7's Quick Launch icon size? Maybe registry?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, taskbar, icons

I recently found out you can enable Quick Launch in Windows 7. The only problem is that the icons are slightly bigger than the original taskbar icons so there's a little gap on the bottom of the taskbar icons.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/vCCCd39.jpg]

Does anyone know how to modify the sizes of those icons through registry or anything really?

If anyone knows their way in registry but doesn't know how I got that Quick Launch in there, basically:

1. Right click taskbar and choose Toolbars > New Toolbar
2. Place "%appdata%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch" in the location bar
3. Unlock the taskbar and hide Text and Title on the Quick Launch menu
4. Make icons Large

That's basically the setup I'm using.

Again, if anyone knows how to make the icons smaller, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If a simple toggle will suffice, I've found an answer.  When hovering mouse cursor over the Quick Launch area, right click and hover on View.  There are two options - Large and Small Icons.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.  You right click on the quick launch on an empty space and select large icons.  Now your icons should be large